# Error in class.phpmailer.php

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am using the phpmailer api to send mails in a joomla site with the RSForm! Pro 1.52.9 component.

All was working ok but today I start to getting the following error when summiting a form build with the RSForm component:

```
   PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in .../libraries/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1182
```

I am using joomla 3.6 and my php version is php 5.3

Comment: the error describes your issue, however you need to put your code which is related with that error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by changing the php version to 5.6.